# How to use Web.UI.WebControls in .NET 8 - I need a html-Unit-Parser

Tags: c#, .net-8.0

I'm migrating an HTML parser from .NET Framework to .NET 8. It is using some types from `System.Web.UI.WebControls`, which is no longer included in the .NET Core Framework.

I installed the nuget package `Web.UI.Webcontrols` 1.0.2.226, but it apparently doesn't export the namespace I need.

[image]

What can I do?

Edit: if the whole package is not functioning: I need to parse a "Unit" ( "3.2em" "12pt" etc.)

PS: It is not helpful to point me to some downloads when I need to migrate a module with other components relying on the defined interface.

Comment: You don't. WebForms was never migrated to .NET Core and was already obsolete by 2010, when ASP.NET MVC 2 came out. .NET 8 is .NET *Core* 8, not a new version of .NET Framework

Comment: `an HTML-Parser from .Net Framework to .Net 8.` why not use [AngleSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AngleSharp/) ? It's very popular (87M downloads) and actively maintained.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Web.UI.WebControls this package? that is dependant on net framework so it wont work under net8, also i imagine the namespace name is 'Web.UI.WebControls' not 'System.web' so change your namespace import. This looks like something that needs replacement rather than a new package version which does not exist.

Comment: @RainerPrem the answer doesn't change. WebForms was never migrated to .NET Core and will never be. You'll either have to rewrite your parser so it *doesn't* depend on WebForms, or you'll have to use a different parser.

Comment: We don't know how your parser works or how you use WebForms to parse units, so we can only make guesses. You could use a regular expression in the correct spot, eg `\d*\.?\d+\s*[A-Za-z]+`. There are [26 possible units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units). You may want to validate them or not. You could also use groups in the regular expression to extract different parts of the unit string, eg `(?<value>\d*\.?\d+)?)\s*(?<unit>[A-Za-z]+)`. You can google for `regex html unit` to find various patterns, eg [this one](https://regexr.com/39424)

Comment: `It is not helpful to point me to some downloads when I need to migrate a module with other components relying on the defined interface` except it is, because that is **the only option**. Microsoft doesn't support ancient WebForms anymore, you need to deal with that and update your software. Just because you don't like this reality doesn't make it any less real.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the sources for WebControls are available on github

https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/UI/WebControls

I used the two files I need directly, and my problem is solved.